# Rails undefined method `image' for error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted to add to my rails app a new model:

```
rails g model Painting patient:references treatment:references image:string
```

I run migration, and then added some lines to the other controllers
In the treatment model:

```
has_many :paintings
```

and in the patient controller

```
has_many :paintings, :through => :treatments
```

As well i updated the routes to:

```
resources :treatments do
 resources :paintings
end
```

So i hoped this is sufficent, to add an imageNAME to an treatment so that i configured the form for the treatment:

```
<%= form_for([@patient, @patient.treatments.build]) do |f| %>

 <div class="field" >
<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
 </div>

 <div class="field" >
<%= f.label :day %>
<%= f.text_field :day, :value => Date.today %>
</div>

         <div class="field" >
         <%= f.label :image %>
         <%= f.text_field :image %>
         </div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

Now with the new :image form i get the error undefined method `image' for #   So i hope somebody knows how to fix this problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the form helper is expecting 'image' to be a method of @patient, rather than 'treatment'. The fields_for helper might be what you need to access the attributes of a related model's fields. Something like this:

```
<% fields_for @patient.paintings do |paintings_fields| %>
  <div class="field" >
    <%= paintings_fields.label :image %>
    <%= paintings_fields.text_field :image %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

See the docs for fields_for here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: Yes thats a good point, i omitted the fields_for!  First i tried something with f.fields_for paintings and than your answer! But i get on both the same error: unknown attribute: painting

Comment: Yes, it **should** be paintings because of the through association: I've edited my answer to reflect that. It sounds like its the association itself that is suspect though... Have you tried out the associations in the console?